# `kill-words` and related commands erase text in read-only buffers

Tags: read-only-mode, kill-text

Killing commands, such as `kill-word`, have started to erase text in read-only buffers. For example, invoking `kill-word` in `dired-mode` or `mu4e-headers-mode` will delete words from a filename or from an email subject, respectively. This has no destructive effects: the files/emails/etc are not themselves affected. Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior?

All my attempts to diagnose it have failed. I tried to bisect the init file, but the issue does not occur immediately after restarting; it happens only after 5–15 minutes of starting the new session, making bisection infeasible.

Comment: *"have started to"* -- Do you see the same thing starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, provide a step-by-step recipe to repro (from `emacs -Q`).

Comment: No, I don’t experience the issue with `emacs -Q`. Unfortunately, I tried to bisect the init file, but the issue does not occur immediately after restarting; it happens only after 5–15 minutes of starting the new session, making bisection infeasible. That’s why I thought of asking here whether anyone had thoughts on what might be causing it.

Comment: Put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time; questions need to stand on their own. Thx.

Comment: My first guess is that something in your config is doing bad things with `inhibit-read-only` (which should only *ever* be bound with some very specific limited scope).

Comment: @Drew: done.

@phils: thank you! I see that `inhibit-read-only` is set to `t`, so with `debug-on-variable-change` I should be able to identify the package that is setting its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the package [consult-mu](https://github.com/armindarvish/consult-mu), which sets the value of `inhibit-read-only` to `t` globally. Reported [here](https://github.com/armindarvish/consult-mu/issues/29).

Thanks to phils for helping me diagnose the issue.